# Жизненный цикл Activity при вызове DialogFragment

Tags: java, android, activity-life-cycle

В `Activity` при клике по кнопке вызывается `DialogFragment` с кнопкой `ОК`. 
Так вот хотел бы понять, при вызове диалогового окна и при `dismiss()` по нажатии по кнопке `ОК`, какие методы жизненного цикла `Activity` вызовутся?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Никакие методы не будут вызваны. Некоторые ошибочно думают, что будут вызываться методы `onPause` и `onResume`, но это не так. У активити эти методы вызовутся только при потере фокуса). Кстати, этот вопрос любят задавать на собеседовании.

Comment: Понятно, благодарю!

Comment: павел а разв у нас вфокесу не диалог бывает?активиж остается на заднем фоне ...

Comment: Нет. Активити фокус теряет, когда в backstack кладут другую активити. Соответственно можно сделать диалог в виде активити, который будет помещаться в backstack и соответственно тогда будут вызываться методы onPause и onResume